# Create XML file from IFS 9

Tags: xml, plsql, ifs-erp

I need to generate a XML file in IFS-9.
I would like to setup the system to generate a XML file every time a shipment is created for a customer order.

Can I do that with a custom SQL event or is there some internal support for this kind of action in IFS 9.
I've been looking for resources on how to do this but found nothing. 
Any hint is most welcome.

Best regards, Kresten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could do that with a custom event and an event action in IFS. Custom event just creates an Oracle trigger in the background, but it is integrated with the IFS front end through the event screens.

1. Create an Oracle directory tied to the folder where you want the XML file to be created.
2. Create a custom event on the shipment table
3. Create an event action for your event with the action type of Execute Online SQL, you can put your code in there to write the XML file to the Oracle Directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Event action type **Application Message** to generate XML out from IFS. Then you don't need to create oracle directory and use IFS integration framework to route the file to the destination.

1. Create Custom Event on Shipment LU
2. Tick the fields you want to include in XML
3. Create new Action of type **Application Message**
4. Create a routing address to send XML to destination
5. Create routing rule and include the address created in 4. [Routing Rule Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqLAn.png). Use the Routing condition MESSAGE_FUNCTION = **EVENT_ID**